# Change timestamp to date in mySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I'm just trying to change my database layout from using time to `date("y-m-d h:i:s")`
would it be possible to do this using just an SQL query? or would I have to manually do one by one?

It's because I started inserting timestamps into the database, now I need to store `date()`, I don't want a simple **bypass** by just converting timestamp to date using PHP, I want to run an SQL to update all rows from timestamps to date.

something like:

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET `time` = 'new_date("y-m-d h:i:S") WHERE `time` = 'time()'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a `DATETIME` type field to store it then you can use a the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function in mysql to convert it.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_date_time DATETIME;
UPDATE my_table SET my_date_time = FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`);
```

documentation on `FROM_UNIXTIME()`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

You can then drop your old column named `time`. I would recommend that anyway because `time` is a column type in mysql.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP `time`;
```